# How to efficiently send Batch Requests through JDBC into MySQL database in Google App Script?

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I am building an application in Google App Maker that takes in a user-input Excel CSV file with 3 columns and 370,573 rows, so in total 1,111,719 data values. I am trying to efficiently input this data into a MySQL database by sending Batch Requests. However, I am unsure of how to properly optimize this process to minimize the amount of time it takes.
This is how I am currently completing the process:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
var data = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO report '
   + '(createdDate, accountFullID, lsid) values (?, ?, ?)');
for(var i = 1; i < **data.length**; i++) {
   stmt.setString(1, data[i][0]);
   stmt.setString(2, data[i][1]);
   stmt.setString(3, data[i][2]); 
   stmt.addBatch();
}
var batch = stmt.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
conn.close();
```

When testing my code, it took upwards of 3 minutes to complete when I set the for-loop to iterate until variable i was less than 500. When I set the value to a small number like 5, it took several seconds to complete. When I set the value to data.length (as it is currently set to in bold), it never completed and timed out with a deadlock exception. How should I edit my code in order to more efficiently execute batches and reduce the total amount of time it takes when inputting all the data entries from the Excel CSV file, not only a small portion of the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one time import, I would use app makers native import function. Create a data model that matches the structure of your cvs document. Then open the csv in a google sheet. make sure the formatting matches the data model and the fields and column names match exactly then use the import function in the top left of the app maker screen. select the google sheet and the data model you created then click import. this should get your data loaded it still make take some time as 1M items is a lot. I see this is 10 months old, so might not have been available back then.

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export